# Boxplot with variable length data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have collected some data in a textfile and want to create a boxplot.
But this datafile contains rows of variable length, for example.

```
1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.5  
1.1, 2.2, 2.9
```

for equal length I could just do

```
PW  = numpy.loadtxt("./learning.dat")  
matplotlib.boxplot(PW.T);
```

How do I handle variable length data lines?

Comment: How should the data be interpreted?  Should all values be concatenated in a single 1D array?

Comment: No, I would like to have boxplots for the datafile columns. So what I'd do in the equal length case would be an m times n array, then boxplot the transpose, right?

Comment: The docs say "x is an array or a sequence of vectors." So you need to read in your data and translate it into a series of vectors, one per box. It looks like you can read it using Python's csv module.

Comment: I have read that, but that's not the issue here. It does work when you have multidimensional arrays. My Problem is, I have sequences of different length and do not know how to feed that into matplotlib.boxplot

Answer (score 29):

Just use a list of arrays or lists. `boxplot` will take any sort of sequence (Well, anything that has a `__len__`, anyway. It won't work with generators, etc.).

E.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [[1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.5],
     [1.1, 2.2, 2.9]]
plt.boxplot(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you're asking how to read in your data, there are plenty of ways to do what you want. As a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def arrays_from_file(filename):
    """Builds a list of variable length arrays from a comma-delimited text file"""
    output = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = np.array(line.strip().split(','), dtype=np.float)
            output.append(line)
    return output

plt.boxplot(arrays_from_file('test.txt'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's funny because if the length is different, the boxplot is plotted the way it should be, but if the lengths are the same, you need to transpose your array.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a boxplot in Plot.ly, using the Python API or just the GUI. I made [this graph](https://plot.ly/~MattSundquist/542), which you can do in the browser or with the [Python API](https://plot.ly/api/python) like this:

```
box1 = {'y': [1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.5],
'type': 'box'}
box2 = {'y': [1.1, 2.2, 2.9],
'type': 'box'}
response = py.plot([box1, box2])
url = response['url']
filename = response['filename']
```

Full disclosure: I am on the Plotly team.

[image]